# ASP.NET: Buttons not working after inserting 'namespace'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace localhost_54355
{

    public partial class UI : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Data Source=dbo\\EmployeeDatabase;Integrated Security=True;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableEmployees(UserName,Email,Password,Job,FirstName,LastName,Location,Phone) VALUES (sdfsd,sdfsdfds, 123456, xcvxcv, xcvxcvcxvx, dfgdfgd, cvbcbcbcb, 123645);", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            try
            {
                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DBRoutines.Insert.Addcompany(TextUserName.Text, txtCo_JobPosition.Text, txtCo_JobPositionDescription.Text, txtCo_Email.Text, int.Parse(txtCo_Phone.Text), txtCo_Address.Text);



        }


        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Panel1.Enabled = true;
            Panel1.Visible = true;
            Panel3.Enabled = false;
            Panel3.Visible = false;

        }
        protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Panel1.Enabled = false;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
            Panel3.Enabled = true;
            Panel3.Visible = true;


        }


        protected void DropDownListJobs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}


My DBRoutines Class:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace localhost_54355
{
    static class DBRoutines
    {
        public static class Insert
        {
            public static void Addcompany(string Employee_UserName, string Employee_Email, string Employee_Password, string Employee_Job, string Employee_FirstName, string Employee_LastName, string Employee_Location, int Employee_Phone, string Employee_CV, string Employee_Availability )
            {
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Database=jobfind;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=1234");

                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("Addcompany", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aUserName", Employee_UserName);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmployee_Email", Employee_Email);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmployee_Password", Employee_Password);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmployee_Job", Employee_Job);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmployee_FirstName", Employee_FirstName);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmployee_LastName", Employee_LastName);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmployee_Location", Employee_Location);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmployee_Phone", Employee_Phone);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmployee_CV", Employee_CV);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmployee_Availability", Employee_Availability);


                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

}

}
```

Hey I'm having a problem implementing a registration page using a MySQL database. When i insert ' namespace localhost_54355 ' in the page's code, my buttons, text boxes, panels, are not recognized. But when i remove the 'namespace', the buttons are becoming available but my class DBRoutines is not recognized. Can you help me identify the problem?

Thanks!

Note:
The variables here ' DBRoutines.Insert.Addcompany(TextUserName.Text, txtCo_JobPosition.Text, txtCo_JobPositionDescription.Text, txtCo_Email.Text, int.Parse(txtCo_Phone.Text), txtCo_Address.Text); ' are not correct. The only correct one is the 'TextUserName.Text' but it's still only recognized when i remove 'namespace'.

Comment: do you added namespace in aspx pages as well?

Comment: just to add to @EhsanSajjad's comment the place to add this is in the `Inherits` attribute of the [`Page Directive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx); it should look like `Inherits="localhost_54355.UI"` with the namespace

Comment: yeah i added: <%@ Import Namespace="localhost_54355" %> in my Register.aspx page

Comment: show codebehind file attribute

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register"   %>
<%@ Import Namespace="localhost_54355" %>

Comment: not sure if this what you asked :P

Comment: @user3644943: your page directive is looking for a class name 'Register' but the class you posted in your question is called `UI`, why the mis-match?

Comment: @DaveParsons oh didnt see your comment, just changed it to that and it works! thank you :)

Comment: @user3644943: looking at your comments and this question leads me to believe you have a bit of fundamental knowledge about namespacing and what it is/means missing. I would highly recommend you take some time to research this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RegisterCustomer.aspx.cs" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" Inherits="Hi_ImTheGreatNamespaceHere!" %>
```

Property name is Inherits .. Add it to the Page Tag